# Определение выбранных из списка вариантов фильтра запроса

Tags: php

Задача: предоставить выбор из списка один или несколько критериев фильтра данных.
Принимаю выбранные варианты фильтра в массив, все ок, циклом `for` поставил условие
Переменные:  `count` подсчет кол-ва элементов массива, `radiop` полученный список фильтра.

```
for ($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++)    
    echo "$radiop[$i]<br>";
print_r ($i);
```

Не получается вывести правильно `$radiop[$i]` предупреждение `"Notice: Undefined offset"`.
Подсчет выводит 6 выбранных пунктов фильтра, `print_r ($i)` выдает 7, хотя их 6.
Вопрос: как правильно вывести выбранные элементы массива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё дело в `$i<=$count`, когда `$count` равно 6, цикл выполнится 7 раз, а в массиве только 6 элементов, Вам нужно заменить условие на `$i<$count`

Comment: Спасибо. Элементарно:)